# Contact Form not working with Thank You message

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, contacts

The HTML and PHP to this contact for can be found on the link, everything works perfectly and l just want to have a message saying "Thank you" or similar when the button "Submit" is pressed. I am not worried about if the end result emails or not. It is just for demonstration purposes.

What amendments need to be made in order for me to retain the error boxes that appear if the given field is blank?

Thank you

Code:

```
<script language="javascript">
    var sa_email_id = '1388-fc728';
    var sa_sent_text = 'Thank you for contacting us. We will get back to you soon.';
</script>

<script language="javascript" src="http://s1.smartaddon.com/sa_htmlform.js"></script>

<div id="sa_contactdiv">
    <form name=sa_htmlform style="margin:0px" onsubmit="return sa_contactform()">
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
            Title:<br>
            <select name="title" size="1">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
                <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
                <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
                <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
                <option value="Dr.">Dr.</option>
                <option value="Prof.">Prof.</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            Name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="name" />
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            E-mail Address: <span style="color:#D70000">*</span><br>
            <input type="text" name="email" required="true" />
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            Subject: <span style="color:#D70000">*</span><br>
            <input type="text" name="subject" required="true" />
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            Message: <span style="color:#D70000">*</span><br>
            <textarea name="message" cols="42" rows="9" required="true">
            </textarea>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <input type="submit" value="Send Message" style="font-weight:bold">
        </td></tr>
    </table>
    </form>

    <div style="padding-top:10px">
        <a href="http://www.smartaddon.com/contact_form.html">Contact Form</a> provided by SmartAddon.com
    </div>
</div>
```

Sa_htmlform:
Sa_contactform:

```
var sa_params='';
function sa_contactform(){
var sa_frm=document.sa_htmlform;
for(i=0; i<sa_frm.elements.length; i++){
var sa_el=sa_frm.elements[i];if(sa_frm.elements[i].name){sa_params+='&'+sa_frm.elements[i].name+'='+encodeURIComponent(sa_frm.elements[i].value);}
if(!sa_el.value && sa_el.getAttribute('required')=='true'){alert('Please complete all required fields');sa_el.focus();return false;}
}
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
s.setAttribute('src','http://www.smartaddon.com/js/postform.js');
document.body.appendChild(s);
return false;
}
function sa_contactsent(){
if(typeof sa_sent_text=='undefined'){sa_sent_text='Thank you for contacting us. We will get back to you soon.';}
document.getElementById('sa_contactdiv').innerHTML=sa_sent_text+'<br><br>Contact Form provided by SmartAddon.com';
}
```

JS:

sa_params += ''; sa_params += ''; sa_params += ''; sa_params += ''; sa_params += ''; var sa_iframe = document.createElement("iframe");document.body.appendChild(sa_iframe); sa_iframe.setAttribute('style', 'width:1px;height:1px;display:none'); var sa_frmcode = '
'+sa_params+'
<'+'script language="javascript">document.pgfrm.submit()<'+'/script>'; sa_iframe.contentWindow.document.write(sa_frmcode); sa_contactsent();

Comment: Could you make the code easier to read? i.e. indentation and new lines

Comment: I am not sure how to do this on this website, sorry (first time today l have used it)

Comment: where is this defined? sa_contactform()

Comment: Cut 'n' paste the code that is formatted - i.e. code that is readable

Comment: Sorry, quite unsure, but if you look here http://www.smartaddon.com/contact_form.html?submit=1

it is a lot clearer to see with a working example. For e-mail address sent to, just type example to get through

Thanks

Comment: Good try at getting my details

Comment: What details are you talking about Ed Heal?

Comment: @GaryBaker - Going to the web site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know, if I understood your questions correctly. 
But if you dont care what happens to the data entered into the form, and just want a message, whether there is something in the form or not, try this:

```
<script language="javascript">
    var sa_sent_text = 'Thank you for contacting us. We will get back to you soon.';
    function sendme() {
        alert(sa_sent_text);
        document.getElementById("name").value = "";
        document.getElementById("message").value = "";
        document.getElementById("subject").value = "";
        document.getElementById("email").value = "";
        return false;
    }
</script>

<div id="sa_contactdiv">
    <form name=sa_htmlform style="margin:0px" onsubmit="return sendme();">
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
            Title:<br>
            <select name="title" size="1">
                <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
                <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
                <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
                <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
                <option value="Dr.">Dr.</option>
                <option value="Prof.">Prof.</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            Name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            E-mail Address: <span style="color:#D70000">*</span><br>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" required="true" />
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            Subject: <span style="color:#D70000">*</span><br>
            <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" required="true" />
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            Message: <span style="color:#D70000">*</span><br>
            <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="42" rows="9" required="true">
            </textarea>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <input type="submit" value="Send Message" style="font-weight:bold">
        </td></tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't think there are any conditions in your html above. I just want an indication if none of the boxes/filed are entered when pressing the Submit button and when they all are just a thank you message on the same or separate page link.

Comment: thats what the *required="true"* attrivute is for.
(my browser displays me a error-message, if nothing is either in one of the fields. If there is something in every field, it displays the message and then does nothing.)

Comment: Obviously l can edit the js. files and html. flies and re upload it onto my web sever and edit the title of the files to reference it within in my domain. It already gives me the empty filed message if any of the forms are empty, that's fine, it works perfectly. All l want is that once all are full/entered it goes and displays a Thank You message. (This message could be on the same page or on a separate aref link.)

Comment: No is does not when you insert it into you webpage. After you fill in all the forms (so no empty error messages appear) and press submit it empties all of the fields and gives you no message.

Comment: Please look here Stefan, l have laid out all of it for you to look at: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=nBNDA1gk0g

Comment: Is javascript enabled in your browser?

Comment: Yes, that is the whole code l copied. If you made those changes on the link, thank you very much. All works now. One more very small thing if l may ask. I would like all the fields to go blank upon pressing submit which displays the Thank You message.

Comment: Yes, Javascript is enabled in my browser

Comment: Thanks @Stefan. I had just one last question, as it is so short l could add it here rather than creating a new thread.

Comment: You know when the message comes up and says thank you, l can edit the words in there myself. However I would like to hide a word in the html text source but then display it in that sentence in the box. i.e when submit, the box will have the words written in the html source code sentence and in the same sentence a phone number. This number is hidden in the source text and only displays in the box.

i.e means that they can only retrieve the phone number when they click submit and not find it in the source. Is this possible? And how?

Comment: this is only possible if you request the phone number not only before you click the button. but this would go beyond the scope of this question, sorry.

Comment: No worries @Stephan. This thread could come in handy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168618/hide-values-from-page-source-but-show-on-page.

Comment: @Stephan, one way may be to obscure the number in the html source as a Hex code which will readily translate to the text numbers/letters in the java-script pop-up box? (average person would not be able to understand the conversion). Sorry ask you all these questions...

Comment: yes, this would be a way, if "hide number from average person" is the task you want to do. ;)

Comment: Definatley, Thank you @Stephan :) Please can you look at what l have written here? Thank you very much! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22286973/write-text-in-hex-code-form